# Arduino leave PWM on

Tags: programming, led, pwm

I am doing an aquarium light sunrise/sunset. Till now programming wise I only did the sunrise. After running the code the light starts to rise up fine, than  at full brightness, it turns off. I want to keep it on after it reaches the 100% pwm and than starts decreasing when it's time to get off. Any help on how to leave the pwm at 100% and than starts to dim when it's time to turn off? I am still new to coding arduino, so explanation need to be for a beginner :P Thanks before hand.

```
#include <DS3231.h>

//Set Variables
int fadeTime = 15; //Fade Time
int onHour = 12; //Light On Hour
int onMin = 00; //Light On Minute
int offHour = 19; //Light On Hour
int offMin = 00; //Light On Minute
int led = 9; //Set pinout with with PWM

DS3231  rtc(SDA, SCL);
Time t;
void start();

void setup()
{
  pinMode(led, OUTPUT);
  rtc.begin();
}

void loop()
{
  t = rtc.getTime();

  // Send Day-of-Week
  Serial.print(rtc.getDOWStr());
  Serial.print(" ");

  // Send date
  Serial.print(rtc.getDateStr());
  Serial.print(" -- ");

  // Send time
  Serial.println(rtc.getTimeStr());

  if (t.hour == onHour && t.min == onMin) //Check Time
  {
    start();
  }

}

void start()
{
  // Fade script
  for (int i = 0 ; i <= 255; i++)
  {
    analogWrite(led, i);
    delay(((fadeTime * 60000)/306));
  }

}
```

Comment: You need to have the program remember whether the light are ON or OFF. That way you can check the see if they are already on, before calling `start`.

Comment: The PWM is not supposed to turn off all by itself: last thing you wrote is 255, and it should stay at that level. It looks to me like this is _not a software problem_, but rather a hardware issue. Just for testing, replace your LED by a low power one (a standard 3 mm or 5 mm LED) in series with a resistor in the 220 Ω – 1 kΩ range. If it works with this setup, then you know it is a power supply issue.

Answer (score 3):

Why not create a global brightness variable (e.g. *cBrightness*) so that you can adjust the brightness accordingly when the time comes? With a global variable, you can still maintain the brightness of the LED even after it exits the *start()* function.

For the *start()* function, you can include one argument (*int/bool* type variable) in the function to determine when to perform the brightening or dimming of the light depending on the RTC timing.

```
void start(int st)
{
  if(st==0)    
  {
     //Brightness decrement function here
  }else if(st==1)   
  {   
     //Brightness increment function here
  }
}
```

For the brightness decrement function, it is the opposite of the increment function:

```
for (int i = 255 ; i >= 0; i--)
{
    analogWrite(led, i);
    delay(((fadeTime * 60000)/306));
}
```

To summarize, the code could look something like this:

```
#include <DS3231.h>

//Set Variables
int fadeTime = 15; //Fade Time
int onHour = 12; //Light On Hour
int onMin = 00; //Light On Minute
int offHour = 19; //Light On Hour
int offMin = 00; //Light On Minute
int led = 9; //Set pinout with with PWM
int cBrightness = 0;  //Current brightness

DS3231  rtc(SDA, SCL);
Time t;
void start(int st);

void setup()
{
  pinMode(led, OUTPUT);
  rtc.begin();
}

void loop()
{
  t = rtc.getTime();

  // Send Day-of-Week
  Serial.print(rtc.getDOWStr());
  Serial.print(" ");

  // Send date
  Serial.print(rtc.getDateStr());
  Serial.print(" -- ");

  // Send time
  Serial.println(rtc.getTimeStr());

  if (t.hour == onHour && t.min == onMin) //Check Time
  {
    start(1);
  }else if (t.hour == offHour && t.min == offMin)
  {
    start(0);
  }
  //Maintains brightness
  analogWrite(led, cBrightness);

}

void start(int st)
{
  if(st==0)     //Will decrement in brightness
  {
   for (int i = 255 ; i >= 0; i--)
   {
    analogWrite(led, i);
    delay(((fadeTime * 60000)/306));
   }
   cBrightness = 0;

  }else if(st==1)   //Will increment in brightness
  {   
   for (int i = 0 ; i <= 255; i++)
   {
    analogWrite(led, i);
    delay(((fadeTime * 60000)/306));
   }
  cBrightness = 255;
  }    
}
```